# Loop over array of user ID's in postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have 2 tables in a postgresql database: 1 with user information (table: users, fields: user_id, username, full_name) and a with a user relation (table: relations, fields: relation_id, user_id_1, user_id_2).

I have a website where a user can login. Say user ID = 1. I want to have a page where I can fetch a list of users, + their relation (follower, following).

Currently, I do this like this:

```
// fetch the user information of user 2
SELECT user_id, username, full_name FROM users WHERE user_id = 2;

// check if user 1 follows user 2
SELECT relation_id FROM relations WHERE user_id_1 = 1 AND user_id_2 = 2;

// check if user 2 follows user 1
SELECT relation_id FROM relations WHERE user_id_1 = 2 AND user_id_2 = 1;
```

The problem is, on some pages I have multiple users to fetch and check. Every user now requires 3 queries, and I want to do this (if possible) in 1 query.

Lets say I have the following array: [2, 3, 4]. I want to fetch the user information of user 2, 3 and 4, and I also want to check the relation between these users and user 1 (because I'm logged in as user 1).

```
// select the user information
SELECT user_id, username, full_name FROM users WHERE user_id IN ([2,3,4]);
```

This query should fetch the user information, but I have no idea how to loop over each item in the query to check the relation between the user in the array and user 1.

Comment: `user_id = any( array [2,3,4] )`

Comment: how can I do this with prepared statements? I'm using nodeJS. ``SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE user_id ANY ($1)`` and as $1 ``userIds.join(',')`` does not work.

Comment: @yesterday: it looks like you're missing the `=` sign before the `any(...)`

Comment: ``SELECT ... FROM users WHERE user_id = ANY($1)``with $1 = ``userIds.join(',')`` does not work. I get an error ``Array value must start with \"{\" or dimension information.``. Replacing $1 with {$1} in the query does not work either.

Comment: OK I got this working now! Someone a solution to join the 3 queries in one query?